# Delphi check dataset for foreignkey Mysql

Tags: mysql, delphi

I have fucntion to check all foreign key constraint , my database has 500 tables , fields with many fk contraints take long time ( 10 sec ):
I use this fucntion in beforepost of dataset like this:

```
  msg := check_foreign_key(Dataset,'employee',field_name);
  if msg <> '' then
  begin
    ShowMessage(msg);
    abort;
    Exit;
  end;
```

how can i reduce this time, this is my function:

```
function check_foreign_key(ds: TDataSet;table_name: string;var ret_field_name: string): string;
var
  qry1,qry2: TUniQuery;
  ref_table:String;
begin
  Result := '';
  qry1 := TUniQuery.Create(nil);
  qry2 := TUniQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry1.Connection := my_db;
    with qry1 do
    begin
      close;
      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('select COLUMN_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME');
      SQL.Add('from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE');
      SQL.Add('where TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + my_db.Database + ''' and TABLE_NAME = ''' + table_name + '''');
      SQL.Add('and referenced_column_name is not NULL');
      Open;
    end;
    qry2.Connection := my_db;;
    while not qry1.Eof do
    begin
      if not DataSet_Has_Field(ds,qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString) then
      begin
        qry1.Next;
        Continue;
      end;
      if ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).IsNull then
      begin
        qry1.Next;
        Continue;
      end;
      with qry2 do
      begin
        close;
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('select count(' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME').AsString + ') as c from ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME').AsString);
        if (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftString) or
           (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftMemo) or
           (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftWideString) then
          SQL.Add('where ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME').AsString + '=''' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString + '''')
        else
          SQL.Add('where ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME').AsString + '=' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString);
        Open;
        if FieldByName('c').AsInteger = 0 then
        begin
            ref_table := qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME').AsString; 
            Result := 'code ' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString + ' not exist in table ' + ref_table;
            ret_field_name := qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString;
            Break;
        end
        else
        begin
          close;
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('show fields from ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME').AsString + ' like ''%active''');
          Open;
          ref_table := FieldByName('field').AsString;
          if recordcount > 0 then
          begin
            close;
            SQL.Clear;
            SQL.Add('select ' + ref_table + ' from ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME').AsString);
            if (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftString) or
               (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftMemo) or
               (ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).DataType = ftWideString) then
              SQL.Add('where ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME').AsString + '=''' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString + '''')
            else
              SQL.Add('where ' + qry1.FieldByName('REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME').AsString + '=' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString);
            Open;
            if FieldByName(ref_table).AsString = 'n' then
            begin
              if ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString <> VarToStr(ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).OldValue) then
              begin
                Result := 'code ' + ds.FieldByName(qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString).AsString + ' not active. ' + #13#10 +
                'Field :' + qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString;
                ret_field_name := qry1.FieldByName('COLUMN_NAME').AsString;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
      qry1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry1);
    FreeAndNil(qry2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Actually this is not delphi problem, mysql information schema is slow.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your `check_foreign_key` to find out what consumes most of its execution time?  In any case, it looks like you ought to be able to do all that fk checking on the server and not have to retrieve it on the client at all